# What are the partial charges in an SN2 transition state?

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution

What are the partial charges of on the atoms in a SN2 reaction?

The nucleophile is normally negatively charged and has a lone pair of electrons. This would make you think the transition state would have a negative charge on the nucleophile. The leaving group also is taking the electrons from the molecule with it. So what is the charge separation?

Here are conflicting images.

**First image**

[image]

**Second image**

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by *So what is the charge separation?* For SN2 reaction of bromide with chloroethane, bromide has -1 charge as reaction "starts" and chloride has -1 charge when the reaction "ends."

Comment: I added some links for clarification.

Comment: ? I don't see any "conflict" between the links. What do you think is different/wrong?

Comment: One has negative charges on both the nucleophile and leaving group. The other has a positive charge on the nucleophile and a negative charge on the leaving group.

Comment: That just isn't correct. For which of the images do you think that there is a positive charge on the nucleophile?!? For the second the leaving atom isn't even shown...

Comment: Take a closer look at the second image. There are partial negative charges on the nucleophile and the leaving group, and a partial positive charge on the carbon center. Your images are in accordance with one another.

Comment: The problem here is you're reading more into partial charge than you should. If ever you take 2 partial negatives and a partial positive, and you can tell the total charge, something is wrong. It's not that detailed.

Comment: So sorry, I linked the wrong image for the second link. https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-5e8619e5b488fb01d32d2fb51c861fa8-c

Comment: Again, I don't see a problem....

Comment: Second image has a positive charge on the nucleophile. The first image has a negative charge on the nucleophile. What is correct?

Comment: Well they are both just diagrams and imperfect representations of what happens. In the second diagram the molecule being attacked is shown with a charge imbalance. I interpret the $\delta^+$ on the nucleophile in the middle image to mean that the positive charge is moving off the molecule being attacked and onto the nucleophile. Hence the nucleophile is donating an electron and the electron is going to the iodine atom which is shown with $\delta^-$.

Comment: I think this illustrates nicely why looking at multiple sources is good. Two different representations get you thinking about what is *really* going on...

Comment: I am more used to seeing the first image... It may depend on whether the nucleophile is initially charged. Maybe we may see a partial positive charge on the nucleophile in the TS if it was originally uncharged and we may see a partial negative charge if it was originally negatively charged.

Comment: I would regard the second image as wrong.

Comment: I suspect that the second image is a typo, and where there is delta+, it should read delta-.